# How to highlight/bookmark lines in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

An old editor I used to use (and still use [UEStudio]) had a nice feature where I could bookmark a line in a file and that line would then be highlighted in the code by a background color of my choice. (See the image below.)

I found it VERY useful when working in larger files. Then when whatever bug/feature you were working on was complete you could just un-bookmark the line and the highlight would go away.

How would I do this in Android Studio?

*(Note, I am not talking about the current line where the cursor is.)*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1 - Select the line(s) you would like to bookmark.

2 - Go to Navigate Menu ==> Bookmarks ==> Toggle Bookmark.

**If you would like to add an alias to the bookmark here are two ways to do it:**

1.1 - For existing bookmarks, go to Navigate Menu ==> Bookmarks ==> Show Bookmarks.

1.2 - Select the desired bookmark then press on the "Edit" icon (the pen).

1.3 - Enter the alias or the description of the bookmark.

**or**

2.1 - Select the line(s) you would like to bookmark & add Mnemonic to.

2.2 - Go to Navigate Menu ==> Bookmarks ==> Toggle Bookmark with Mnemonic.

2.3 - Enter the mnemonic desired.

Comment: [to expand the answer] you can also use shortcuts. F11 - book/unbook; SHIFT+F11 - show list of bookmarks in the project.